# I'm not sure about using the word "Blau"

Tags: adjective, compound-adjective

**Foreword**
Since there are few left free names for .com domain, we struggle to find something that is still free and sounds well.
Since I wanted to register the domain "bluedata.com" but it was already taken, I ended up to register the domain "blaudata.com".

Even if I'm studying a little German I actually didn't realize that it could be grammatically wrong, because if blau is intended as adjective then it should be conjugated to case and gender, and it would be "blauen data" (right?).

**Question**
So I'd like to ask if BlauData could have any sort of sense in German and if it sounds somehow acceptable or it sounds completely wrong.

Comment: The owner of http://www.blaudata.at/ seems to think it makes sense.

Comment: It's a minor nitpick, but only verbs are "conjugated"; everything else is "declined". Both are "inflected". Also, welcome to German SE! I've noticed that many newbies forget to accept an answer. You might want to wait a day or so everyone has a chance to answer if they want, then click the check mark next to the answer that best responds to your question. This encourages people to give helpful answers in the future.

Comment: I don't think that BlauData in German makes more sense than bluedata makes sense in English.

Comment: Don’t ignore that „Blau“ is, apart from the colour, a synonym for „intoxicated“. If you provide information that is sensitive to that cognate, I’d rather not use that domain

Comment: It depends on the target audience for your domain. "blaudata" or "blau data" does not make any sense in German. "blau" is a German word, "data" is (probably) English. In company names and marketing sometimes strange word combinations or  unusual spelling or pronunciation are used, which sometimes results in a need to explain the intended pronunciation. Examples: "playmobil", "BahnCard". In this context, "data" can be pronounced in an English or German way, even if it is not a German word. Note that there is a mobile phone provider (reseller) named "blau", so "blaudata" might seem related.

Comment: @tofro ... and in english "blue" also means "sad". "red" could be communist, "brown" the opposite, "green" ecological or just good ... und alle Theorie ist grau.

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

> uppercase and lowercase letters are ignored for domains

Then, grammatically correct would be "blaue Daten".

And at least, I think website names are not really checked for grammatical correctness. So just choose a name that *speaks*, *sounds*, and *makes sense* for your website.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but extended comments that are too long to fit in the comments. First, you may want to consider your audience; since "blaudata" actually makes sense in German then you might be getting German speaking visitors who will be surprised to see your site is in English. (You didn't say that, but I'm assuming since you said you're just learning German.) Conversely, some English speaking potential visitors might be put off because "blaudata" sounds German and will also be expecting a site in German.

Also, German adjectives have complex declension rules. What SwissCodeMen (who would know better than I) said is true that the grammatically correct form would be *blaue Daten*. But so is *Das sind meine blauen Daten,* and *Es gibt keine blauen Daten.* It depends on how the phrase is used in a sentence.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the singular of *Daten* in German is *Datum* as in Latin. English tends to treat "data" as an uncountable singular noun, meaning it uses verbs conjugated in the singular but does not require an article. For example "The data speaks for itself." & "We need data in order to reach a conclusion." There are a few professorial types that use "data" the "correct" way: "These data are clear." AFAIK German still keeps the singular *Datum* and the plural *Daten* though a few borrowed expressions use the English phrasing, e.g. *das Datamining*. So while "blaudata" makes sense in German, I think it will still sound a little English to German speakers.

Comment: Some companies play a strange game where they are using names that suggest a nation/language different  the one they are acually from. For example, there is a US ice cream brand with a name supposed to sound Danish. If the questioner wants to play that game then using *blau* fits.

Comment: @RHa: Yes, even if you're from Brooklyn you can put an umlaut in the name and people think your ice cream is "European". I'm afraid a lot of Americans are like that; buy a product with a foreign sounding name? Sure. Actually learn a foreign language? No thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers already explained, it would be "blaue Daten" in german. But instead of an adjective, you could use a compound noun: "Blaudaten" (compare to e.g. "Blaulicht").

In any case, since you're mixing words from different languages here, I don't think any grammar rule really applies. The real concern is: does it "feel" right? At least to me, it seems okay. It's clear that it's something about data and the colour blue. I don't really like the mixing of languages, but I wouldn't get the impression the writer was illiterate or stupid.